# how to copy the value of a calculated collumn to another collumn

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, copy-item

I have a list with a calculated column (the column takes the value from another column but when there is a value in a second column the calculated column has to take that value `=IF(Budget="";[Budget PlusMin];Budget)`.

I want to use the calculated column value in a flow to assign the value to a normal list item but I can't choose for it. It doesn't show up in the flow.

I can not use sharepoint designer. Is there a possibility to copy the value of a calculated column?

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to replace the calculated collumn. I used a flow "when an existing item is modified" I did the action "item update" to put automatically the value `Budget PlusMin` in the previous named calculated field. Then I tested if the `Budget` collumn had aan amount > than 0, If yes, then I used 'item update' to put the amount `Budget` into the previous named calculated collumn. And now I can use that collumn to work within a flow.

But I'm very glad with the answers from Venkat Konjeti. I 'll certainly use that link to have more information about writing code. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

I can use the calculated column in Microsoft Flow which I am using to insert the values to another list item. See my below flow

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me know which flow template you used?

Comment: I have created a custom flow and also got this worked in OOB Templates (Send a customized email when a new SharePoint list item is added)

Comment: I use "when an existing list item is modified, complete a custom action"

Comment: I want the calculated collomn to become a simple numeric list item. I can't use Designer.

Comment: Will you be able to copy the calculated column to another list item which is your first question? About conversion,  you can use "Data Operations" action. You can refer the formulas here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language